# 'program already running"? NOT

Tags: google-chrome, login

When I try to log on to Google Chrome & Gmail, my PC tells me the program is already running and won't let me log on.  Where can I find and kill this phantom program?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Windows, you can open the Task Manager, make sure the Processes tab is selected, and then find and kill the `chrome.exe` processes.